# Replacing all words and letters with '' in pandas using .replace()

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I am currently scraping into a database where I get minimum orders of product like: "3 Boxes", "1 Kilogram", "9 Cases".
I would like to eliminate all words accompanying numbers and get only the numbers.

My code to filter those exceptions is:

```
import pandas as pd

min_order = element.find_element_by_class_name('gallery-offer-minorder').find_element_by_tag_name('span').text.replace(' Pieces', '').replace(' Piece', '').replace(' Units', '').replace(
        ' Unit', '').replace(' Sets', '').replace(' Set', '').replace(' Pairs', '').replace(' Pair', '').replace('Boxes', '').replace('Box', '').replace('Bags', '').replace('Bag', '').replace('Carton', '').replace('Acre', '').replace('Kilograms', '').replace('Kilogram', '')
```

My code works for all the cases I tried until I get an exception I haven't noticed. I want to know if it is any way to do this procedure using less lines of code and to eliminate all letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can split the text and get only the 1st part which is the number

```
min_order = element.find_element_by_class_name('gallery-offer-minorder').find_element_by_tag_name('span').text.split(" ")[0]
```